implementing a weighted average in tensorflow
My goal is have a layer which performs a weighted average of the previous dense layer. The output of this weighted layer should be 1 element and be able to pass into subsequent layers.
I saw this code here: Weighted Average: Custom layer weights don't change in TensorFlow 2.2.0
I modified the return from tf.reduce_sum(weightsinputs, axis=-1)  to tf.reduce_sum(weightsinputs)
Sadly, this gives me the following error, "ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero"
Any ideas how I can fix this/what is actually causing the issue?
My guess: The problem is (I think) that when I tf.reduce_sum(...) reduces this to a scalar that somehow this confuses tf. maybe tf is looking for trainable nodes (which there aren't any) so that is why it thinks it is getting a zero, but really it is getting a scalar.
Also, I should mention that I am trying to use a concatenation layer to concatenate multiple of these weighted average sum points...
Thank you!!!!
